# Pandas: Aggregate to longest set

Tags: python, pandas

How can I get the unique entries from a dataframe such as the following; in the first case realizing that many are overlapping and thus do not need to be counted in the final output. I feel like this is perhaps a substring search problem but I am unclear as to what might be a good approach.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
                   "filepath": ['src', 'src/abc', 'src/abc/cde',
'src/abc/cde/main', 'src/abc/cde/main/detach', 'dl/path',
                            'src', 'dl/path']})

   id                 filepath
0   1                      src
1   1                  src/abc
2   1              src/abc/cde
3   1         src/abc/cde/main
4   1  src/abc/cde/main/detach
5   1                  dl/path
6   2                      src
7   2                  dl/path
```

```
expected = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 2],
                         "filepath": ['src/abc/cde/main/detach, dl/path', 'src, dl/path']})

   id                          filepath
0   1  src/abc/cde/main/detach, dl/path
1   2                      src, dl/path
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one of the options :

```
out = (df.assign(filepath=df["filepath"].str.split("/"))
            .explode("filepath").drop_duplicates(keep="last")
            .groupby(level=0).agg({"id": "first", "filepath": "/".join})
            .groupby("id", as_index=False).agg(", ".join)
)
```

Output :
​

```
print(out)

   id                          filepath
0   1  src/abc/cde/main/detach, dl/path
1   2                      src, dl/path
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Define a lambda function to concatenate the unique substrings in each group

   ```py
   def longest_unique_paths(paths):
       sorted_paths = sorted(paths, key=lambda x: len(x), reverse=True)
       result = []

       for path in sorted_paths:
           if not any(path.startswith(p + '/') for p in result):
               result.append(path)

       return ', '.join(result)
   ```
2. Group the DataFrame by the 'id' column and apply the lambda function to the 'filepath' column

   ```py
   res = expected.groupby('id')['filepath'].apply(unique_substrings).reset_index()

   print(res)
   ```

Comment: hm thanks! This does not seem to be able to get to the expected output however.

Comment: sorry, mixed up the inputs! should work now